# How can I keep connector's configuration between restarts when using confluentinc/cp-server-connect docker image extended with new connector

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using confluentinc/cp-server-connect (https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-server-connect) with elasticsearch sink connector (https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch) i added trough dockerfile and rebuilding the image and it works just fine. I'm configuring the connector using http requests like it's done in this tutorial https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-elasticsearch-connector-tutorial/.
My problem is that I couldn't find a way to keep the connector configuration i set during removing and stopping again the docker container with this image.

I couldn't find any mentions of keeping configuration in docker image's documentation on docker hub or by googling it. I also tried manually searching in the image for where this configuration may be stored but i had no luck. Where should I point with docker volume to save this configuration, or maybe the configuration is kept somewhere else like in a specific topic in kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the configurations are kept on Kafka topic. The Connect container doesn't store them.

Therefore, don't restart the Kafka (or Zookeeper) container(s), and your configs will be maintained.